# How to construct a magento theme demo site?

Tags: magento, themes, demo

Now I need to construct a magento theme demo site holding dozens of themes, but there are several problems remaining to to be solved.

1. Usuallly, administrators can change a site's theme through admin panel, but this is unfriendly and inefficient to users. Is it possible to set the theme programmatically, in order to allow users choosing themes in the frontend to see the effects?
2. According to my understanding, when a user chooses to try some theme, the demo site will change its theme settings accordingly. So, how to hold themes on a single site and allow users browsing them simultaneously without interference?

Hope for good suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should post some things that you have tried... however I see the ability to set up each site as subdomains and use a frameset or an iframe to provide the switching from theme to theme.

Comment: If always setting up a site for every single theme, it will require a large amount of disk space to hold them. Considering the rented space is limited, I just want to demonstrate dozens of themes on one site.

Comment: Setting up a storefront / site in Magento takes nearly zero disk space as all it requires is a subfolder, an htaccess file, index.php and 3 symlinks. Are you new to Magento???

Comment: Your suggestion sounds workable. However, does it bring independent backend and settings for different sites?

Comment: No, this is what I'm suggesting - one singular Magento install - and your 'dozens' of themes would all be storefronts within Magento that you could iframe with a store switcher. I will post this as an answer so you can accept as a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set up one multi-store Magento install, and set each storefront to a new theme.**

This can be done under the store view scope of `system > config > general > design > theme / package`

[image: Enter your theme and package here under the store view scope of the config panel]

I see the ability to set up each site as subdomains and use a frameset or an iframe to provide the switching from theme to theme.

Setting up a storefront / site in Magento takes nearly zero disk space as all it requires is a subfolder, an htaccess file, index.php and 3 symlinks. See here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

In essence, your 'dozens' of themes would all be storefronts within Magento that you could iframe with a store switcher.